# MOSFET Heating in LED Driver Circuit

Tags: pwm, led-driver, powermosfet

[image]I have designed LED Driver circuit using IRF540 and use PC817 Optocoupler for isolation.

However, the MOSFETs are heating too much after giving the PWM Signal.

One of my LED panels is 110W. What could be the reason for this?

The schematic is below, let me know if any modification in the circuit if required.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Show your design goals for current and voltage at each node

Comment: pls share your board images.

Comment: Please have a look at my board image...
this was the earlier version of my board and I am updating the board design.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way for your MOSFET to turn off.

[image]

*Figure 1. Move R39.*

The problem is that when the opto turns on Q1's gate capacitance is charged up. When the opto turns off there is no discharge path. If the gate voltage gradually leaks away Q1 will gradually turn off resulting in substantial current through it while there is substantial voltage across it so the power will increase drastically.

By moving R39 to the position shown the 'on' condition won't change but there is a discharge path for the gate. Turn off should be very fast.

Comment: The CTR will not support these R values with 24V (-1)

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I didn't check any of that aspect of the design - only the obvious lack of gate discharge.

Answer (score 5):

Faults

- The input cap shunts the AC signal
- The Vgs is not 0 to 12V
- input & output current is too high for Opto
- PC817X Series is obsolete

Fixed

[image]

- Change input R=760 ohm to ~5mA = (5-1.2V)/R
- Change output Ice to 1mA , Both R's = 10k~12k

Answer (score 3):

Capacitor C11 is causing your PWM signal to look more like a dc voltage, which is not the right way to drive the MOSFET. Furthermore, the voltage divider formed by R10 and R39 is lowering the gate drive voltage, which is not the right way to drive the MOSFET.

Try removing C11 and R39 to get a better PWM signal at the MOSFET's gate.